# ASP CompareValidator and NOT submitting form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, submit, comparevalidator

I have a textbox and a submit button. The textbox is a date-entry field.

Attached to it, I have a compare validator with the type set to "date". It does validate and show an error message.

Problem is, the user can still click on the submit button. I'd like to prevent that. If the user has entered something like 03/hello/2011, he or she should not be able to submit the form.

How can I accomplish this?

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Associate the validator and the submit button in a single validation group. Both of them have the property validation group. Provide a name say pageValidation to both the control's property.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem myself, that a page with validation errors can still continue on to submission when the user clicks the submit button.

What you can do is something like this :

```
    protected void submitClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsValid)
        {
           // somehow the user was able to submit their form even though there are
           // validation errors. Stop here and let ASP.NET present the error messages
           // to the user
           return; 
        }

        // do submission stuff here like putting things in the database
    }
```